# Combine columns of urls into one column in R

Tags: r, merge

I have three columns of Facebook, Twitter, and Instagram URLS like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(fb_url = c("www.facebook.com/...", "www.facebook.com/...",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                 tw_url = c(NA, NA, "www.twitter.com/...", "www.twitter.com/...",NA,NA),
                 ig_url = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "www.instagram.com/...", "www.instagram.com/..."))
> df
fb_url                    tw_url               ig_url
www.facebook.com/...      NA                   NA
www.facebook.com/...      NA                   NA
NA                        www.twitter.com/...  NA
NA                        www.twitter.com/...  NA
NA                        NA                   www.instagram.com/...
NA                        NA                   www.instagram.com/...
```

and I just want to merge them into one column that'd look like this:

```
url
www.facebook.com/...
www.facebook.com/...
www.twitter.com/...
www.twitter.com/...
www.instagram.com/...
www.instagram.com/...
```

`paste0` and `union` are giving me errors, and I think I'm overcomplicating this idea.

Comment: `df %>% transmute(url = coalesce(!!! .))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns are all `factor` (as `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` by default in `data.frame` call), so it can be converted to `character` class and then use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     mutate_all(as.character) %>%
     transmute(url = coalesce(!!! .))
#            url
#1  www.facebook.com/...
#2  www.facebook.com/...
#3   www.twitter.com/...
#4   www.twitter.com/...
#5 www.instagram.com/...
#6 www.instagram.com/...
```

Comment: and here I was going to answer something using the ``www`` pattern. Nice and simple answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it using base R:

```r
df <- data.frame(fb_url = c("www.facebook.com/...", "www.facebook.com/...",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                 tw_url = c(NA, NA, "www.twitter.com/...", "www.twitter.com/...",NA,NA),
                 ig_url = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "www.instagram.com/...", "www.instagram.com/..."),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data.frame(url = na.omit(unlist(df)),
           row.names = NULL)
#>                     url
#> 1  www.facebook.com/...
#> 2  www.facebook.com/...
#> 3   www.twitter.com/...
#> 4   www.twitter.com/...
#> 5 www.instagram.com/...
#> 6 www.instagram.com/...
```

Comment: you do not need `lapply` just do `data.frame(url = na.omit(unlist(df)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `unite` from `tidyr` package:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character) ## convert data frame to character class 
tidyr::unite(df, url, na.rm = T) ## then merge all the columns into url column with removing nas

#   url
#1  www.facebook.com/...
#2  www.facebook.com/...
#3   www.twitter.com/...
#4   www.twitter.com/...
#5 www.instagram.com/...
#6 www.instagram.com/...
```